# How To recognise which finger type - whether it is index,middle etc

Tags: ios

How To recognise in iOS which finger I used for tap in iOS; 
Left hand, Thumb: off Index: on Middle: on Ring: off Pinky: off

Comment: iOS can't possibly know.

Comment: I have two questions: Why does it matter? And why do you/the system need to know?

Comment: @The-Rooster  I Want to know in app that Which finger User Used on tab Screen.

Comment: Even if this *were* possible, you'd have to consider all the other things one might use on a touchscreen: toes, nose, other body parts, conductive gloves, a stylus, [cold sausage](http://www.engadget.com/2010/02/11/south-korean-iphone-users-turn-to-sausages-as-a-cold-weather-me/), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that it cannot be done.

It is not something Apple could/would generate either as their code is designed for an extremely broad audience and something like finger sizes is a huge variant - A 7ft person may have enormous fingertips while a young child has very small fingertips. Also some users use their thumbs and others use their index fingers.

IF, and I say a BIG if, is if you wished to create this, you would have to create something that stored a user initially, asked them to go through touching a certain point on the screen for every finger, store their finger touches (assuming they consistently touched in the same manner almost 100% of the time- soft touches would cover less area so consistency would very difficult to conjure an algorithm to recognise correctly) and then assume that they would be touching certain things on a screen that was modern enough to recognise and measure accurately the specific space being touched on a screen.